# jqGrid using a navGrid with position=right doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've got a jsfiddle with jqGrid here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/3953/

```
var data = [[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"], [48769, "APPR", "", "77733337", "ENTERED"]];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    autowidth: true,
    toppager: true,
    scroll: 1,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
    viewrecords: true,
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"},
    {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date"},
    {
        name: 'blank',
        index: 'blank',
        width: 30},
    {
        name: 'number',
        index: 'number',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"},
    {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"}
    ],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
});

var names = ["id", "thingy", "blank", "number", "status"];
var mydata = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    mydata[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
    $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}

var pager = '#grid_toppager';
$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', pager, {refresh: true, search:false, edit: false, view:false, del: false, add: false, position: 'right'})
        .navButtonAdd(pager, {
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-newwin",
            onClickButton: null,
            position: "last",
            title: "",
            cursor: "pointer",
            caption: ""
        });
```

If you take a look at line 54, you'll see that I'm setting the "position" of the navgrid to right. The buttons are completely disappearing. If I set it to "left" or "center", they seem to work as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a legitimate bug in jqGrid? By the way, I do need to keep the "toppager" and "scroll" elements as they are.

Comment: It poked through the code a bit, and it looks like the control is rendering HTML to put the navgrid buttons on the right, but it's not correct. I think I'm getting a bit lost in the layers of styles being used in the grid...

Comment: I realize I posted the wrong jsfiddle. Here's the correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/3972/

Comment: I've got this as a question on the official triand forums too, but it isn't getting any traction either. You can find that here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-using-a-navgrid-with-positionright-doesnt-seem-to-work/ Does anyone need more information to help with this?

Comment: Any chance Oleg has read or is reading this? I'd love to know if I'm just messing up something easy or if this is a legitimate jqGrid bug.

Answer (score 0):

The view text is covering up the buttons. If you change "viewrecords" from true to false, you'll see your buttons all nice and happy.

As you don't have the page buttons enabled it doesn't make a lot of sense to have the view records anyways, so your probably good just setting them to false. But if you do want both then you'll need to play with some css to move the page buttons over.